# How can I dynamically increase a rate limiters limit?

Tags: go

I'm using `golang.org/x/time/rate` for rate limiting api requests.

```
lim := rate.NewLimiter(rateLimit, burstLimit)

for range time.NewTicker(time.Second).C {
    fmt.Println(time.Now(), "tick")
    go func() {
        res := lim.Reserve()
        if res.OK() && res.Delay() == 0 {
            fmt.Println(time.Now(), "done")
        } else {
            fmt.Println(time.Now(), "dropped")
            res.Cancel()
        }
    }()
}
```

For allowed requests that can execute immediately, it may sometimes be necessary to retry the request. Those retried requests should not count against the rate limit. Using `res.Cancel()` in that case does not return the reserved token to the pool due to https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/time/+/1f47c861:rate/rate.go;l=161.

How can reserved tokens be unreserved or the limiter's status adjusted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It feels horribly hacky, but it seems one can use [`ReserveN`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/time/rate#Limiter.ReserveN) or [`AllowN`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/time/rate#Limiter.AllowN) with negative values to return tokens to the pool: https://play.golang.org/p/yt0RS3MJOpi

```golang
    lim := rate.NewLimiter(rate.Every(3*time.Second), 1)

    for range time.NewTicker(time.Second).C {
        fmt.Println(time.Now(), "tick --")
        go func() {
            if lim.Allow() {
                fmt.Println(time.Now(), "allow")
                time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(20)) * time.Millisecond)

                if rand.Intn(2) == 0 {
                    lim.AllowN(time.Now(), -1)
                    fmt.Println(time.Now(), "revert")
                }
            } else {
                fmt.Println(time.Now(), "drop")
            }
        }()
    }
```

The example shows that whenever an allowed operation is reverted, the next one is allowed too.

Comment: I can confirm this is working fine now in production

Answer (score 1):

You want [rate.Reservation.Cancel()](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/time/rate#Reservation.Cancel) - which does a best effort at "undoing" a reservation - considering the concurrent usage of a rate-limiter.

From the docs:

> Cancel is shorthand for CancelAt(time.Now()).
>
> CancelAt indicates that the reservation holder will not perform the
> reserved action and **reverses the effects of this Reservation on the
> rate limit as much as possible**, considering that other reservations
> may have already been made.

Comment: As I wrote Cancel seems to compare the reservation time with time.Now() and is a nop if reservation time has passed. Hence this approach won‘t work unless reservations target a future point in time.

Comment: Apologies, totally missed you referenced `Cancel()` in your post...    If the reservation time has passed, isn't that request's token consumption effectively over, and not counting towards the rate limit at that moment in time?

Comment: See what I've tried above- does that sound reasonable?